# What's the Vim's version of Emacs's upcase-initials-region?

Tags: letter-case

What's the Vim's version of Emacs's `upcase-initials-region`?

Viz., how do I capitalize only the first letter in words (preferably without a regex)?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built-in as far as I know.

I don't know how smart `upcase-initials-region` in emacs is, assuming it just capitalizes beginning of the words in the region...

The easiest way would be using `:s` command with regex which for some reason you prefer not to use, but still:

```
:s/\<./\u&/g
```

You can turn into a command:

```
command! -range UpcaseInitials <line1>,<line2>s/\<./\u&/g
```

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [the abolish plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) and its coercion mode for changing case (beyond simple upper/lower case transformations, for which `gu`, `gU`, and `g~` work well).

For example, `crt` was the titlecase coercion. It’s documentation is gone, but the feature should still exist ([commit reference](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish/commit/8fe5966961fc047f7f93b4158a418e54d1c205ff)).

Comment: It seems something could be done with `gu`,`gU`,`g~`… but maybe not without recording a macro?

Comment: Perhaps something like `guiw~` for an individual word @Geremia

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this on a visual selection:

```
:s/\<\(\w\)\(\w*\)\>/\u\1\L\2/g
```

I need to try Maxim Kim's approach in this thread, though, because its so much simpler.

Comment: Actually your version might be better, as it lowercases the rest of the word.

Comment: @MaximKim I wish I could say it's mine, but I stole it from somewhere. I still want to see firsthand what yours does. If I don't use a particular regex frequently, it looks like someone picked up the phone while I was connected to a BBS.

Comment: Note that if you want the selection to be more fine-grained than linewise, you’d need `\%V`

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me before jut now, but this doesn't do the job properly if the line has words contaianing an apostrophe. "maybe she's born with it; maybe it's maybelline" becomes "Maybe She'S Born With It; Maybe It'S Maybelline."

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That's never come up with me before. I only use that regex on headers, which are on their own line. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: With a slightly modified regex `:s/\v<(\w)(\S+)/\u\1\L\2/g`, you would lowercase all non-whitespace characters `\S`. I also used `+` instead of `*` to skip single-letter words completely. Good if there's an "a" in the title, bad if the title starts with "A" :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Using macros

A macro solution was suggested in the comments. I did already think about it but there's one problem I could not solve. Let's hope someone smarter than me can figure something out.

The commands to capitalize the letter under the cursor and jump to the next word is quite simply `gUlw`. To record it as a macro in register `u`ppercase, type `qugUlwq`. Now we can `@u` through a line. So far, so good.

Usually, we'd record a recursive macro like `quqqugUlw@uq` to run several times. Problem is, that `w` will jump to the next word - even if it's on the next line. This makes sense in the general case but here it will capitalize *every word until the end of the buffer*. We'd need to force a failure at the end of the line. While I could come up with a complicated solution, why make it complicated if you can just use `:substitute`?

The best I can suggest with a macro is hitting `@@` repeatedly - which does not really live up the ease of use of other answers.

### Using external commands

Another way to do it *without regular expressions* is to filter the line through an external command. Using `:.!` to delegate to a simple Python script that applies title-case (or at least [Python's flawed stab at it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)) could look like this:

```
:.!python -c "import fileinput; [print(i.title(), end='') for i in fileinput.input()]"
```

Or as a mapping to e.g. <kbd>F4</kbd>:

```
:nnoremap <F4> <Cmd>.!python -c "import fileinput; [print(i.title(), end='') for i in fileinput.input()]"<CR>
```

Feel free to pick your favorite scripting language instead. Is it possible to call Emacs in scripting mode and call its `upcase-initials-region`?

### But really... regular expressions

There's nothing evil about regular expressions. Sure, they may be hard to read at times, sometimes you really need to decipher them but they're just a tool. Using the best tool for the job means using `:s` with a regex to capitalize every word.

Comment: I wonder about title-casing fOo: I suggest guiw~ in comments below, but there may be words for which you don’t want to change the casing of inner letters (and for which your approach is therefor superior).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble good point. I'm totally ignorant of Emacs and followed OP's description to the letter: "capitalize first letter of each word". Proper title casing is even more complicated as there are some words that never get capitalized, e.g. articles. I never tried vim-abolish but I guess a plugin would be the way to go.

Comment: RE: ignore of emacs; uh, same :)